# Get the boundary edges of outer and inner polygons in a 3D mesh with holes in python

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, edges

I have a bunch of meshes with different shapes (cuboids, L-shapes, pentagons, hexagons, ...) with holes, see attached image. The meshes are not flat, not always vertical, have different orientations and they are volumetric (with thickness). How can I get the boundary of edges on the **outer** polygon (pentagon in below picture) and **inner** polygon (the holes)? The following code is the closest I could get but it returns all the boundary vertices I believe.

```py
def get_boundary(object):
    """ get the boundary of the mesh """
    # This returns more vertices than the boundary!!!
    
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(obj.data)

    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
    boundary = []
    for edge in bm.edges:
        if edge.is_boundary:
            coords = [vert.co for vert in edge.verts]
            boundary.extend(coords)

    # print(np.unique(np.asarray(boundary), axis=0)) # this sorts the points
    
    return boundary
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to select coplanar faces on one side of the mesh.
`bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='COPLANAR', threshold=0.1)`
Now I should make a new mesh from it, then `is_boundary` should give me the inner and outer polygon. But how should I create a new mesh from the selection in the edit mode and make sure the properties of edges are updated?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by the boundary. I have a guess, but I don't want to suggest something and possibly push you in the wrong direction. In your code, you check edges for `is_boundary`. A boundary edge is an edge that has only one face neighbor. So if you have a quad made out of 4 vertices, all edges are boundary. If you now subdivide it, all edges created by subdividing previous edges, are still boundary, but all edges created by cutting the face are internal, not boundary. After solidifying, no edge is a boundary.

Comment: I think you want `is_convex` instead. See the docs https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMEdge.is_convex

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Sorry for the unclarity. I added one more image that shows in wireframe mode what edges I meant by inner and outer polygons. I can convert quads to triangles, so let's suppose we only have tris.

Comment: @Gorgious I think most of the edges are convex. If I use `is_convex` a lot of edges are selected.

Comment: Check the normal of both faces adjacent to an edge, if their normal il more than x% different, they might be part of the set you're looking for. I don't know of a builtin topological tool to separate the sets you're looking for.

Comment: @Gorgious I'm using coplanar faces to select the set, please see my last update. but how should I update the edges property with this new subset of faces?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample in Blender scripting. I used `bmesh.ops.edgeloop_fill` to get the edge loops after making a subset of `coplanar faces`. This code runs in Blender scripting but I can't run this in a standalone python using API without Blender UI, this line troubles me: `bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='COPLANAR', threshold=0.1)`. I don't know how to handle the active data between functions. @Gorgious  any improvements, comment and corrections is appreciated.

```py
def get_largest_face_inx(obj):
    """ get the index of the largest face """

    areas = [poly.area for poly in obj.data.polygons]
    
    return np.argmax(areas)

def select_coplanar_faces(obj):
    """ select coplanar faces """
    
    # get the index of the largest face by area
    inx = get_largest_face_inx(obj)
    
    # select coplanar faces of this largest face
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    obj.data.polygons[inx].select = True  
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='FACE')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='COPLANAR', threshold=0.1)
    
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    coplanars = [f for f in bpy.context.object.data.polygons if f.select is True]
    
    return coplanars

def full_copy(obj):
    obj_copy = bpy.context.active_object.copy()
    obj_copy.data = obj_copy.data.copy()
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj_copy)
    obj_copy.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj_copy
    
    return obj_copy

### MAIN Function
obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj_copy = full_copy(obj)
obj.select_set(False)

# coplanar = select_coplanar_faces_bmesh(obj)
coplanar = select_coplanar_faces(obj_copy)
#print(get_mesh_area(obj))
print(sum([f.area for f in coplanar]))

#-------------------------------------------

#select_convex_loop(obj)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='INVERT')  # necessary to separate selected coplanars
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED')    # create a new mesh from selected faces

obj_active = bpy.context.active_object
print(obj_active.name)

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='FACE')
bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY') 

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='EDGE')
me = obj_active.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
#bm.faces.active = None
        
ret = bmesh.ops.edgeloop_fill(bm,
        edges=[e for e in bm.edges if e.is_boundary])
        
        
# the seperate edge loops
edge_loops = [f.edges[:] for f in ret["faces"]]

print(len(edge_loops))


loop_areas = [f.calc_area() for f in ret["faces"]]
print(loop_areas)

areas = [f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces]
        

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

[image]